# Match numbers separated with colons, semicolons optionally

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:
objectsA=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;:objectsB=

And I want to know how can I match, optionally, the numbers inside `objectsA` and `objectsB` but put into consideration, that may one or another can be empty. For example:

`objectsA` can be:

```
objectsA=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;
```

But also can be

```
objectsA=:objectsB=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;
```

Or even

```
objectsA=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;:objectsB=objectsA=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;
```

The current code:

```
$line2 = "
2016-07-31 00:39:00 debian-8gb-sfo2-01 gdeliveryd: notice : formatlog:trade:roleidA=3328:roleidB=2161:moneyA=0:moneyB=0:objectsA=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;:objectsB=";

if (strpos($line2, ':trade:roleidA=3328') > 0) {
    if (!preg_match('/([\d-: ]+)\s*.*\sformatlog:trade:roleidA=(\d+):(.*)roleidB=(\d+):moneyA=(\d+):moneyB=(\d+):objectsA=(regexhere):objectsB=(regexhere).*$/', $line2, $c)) {
        // error occured
    }
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($c);
}
```

And the problems is that the current regex `((\d+\,\d+\,\d\;)+|)` has an weird behavior, that can't happen.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-07-31 00:39:00 debian-8gb-sfo2-01 gdeliveryd: notice : formatlog:trade:roleidA=3328:roleidB=2161:moneyA=0:moneyB=0:objectsA=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;:objectsB=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;
    [1] => 2016-07-31 00:39:00 
    [2] => 3328
    [3] => 
    [4] => 2161
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;
    [8] => 38155,39,1;
    [9] => 38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;
    [10] => 38155,39,1;
)
```

For some reason, if the objects has the same size, the regex are creating a new array index, which shouldn't happen.

The expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-07-31 00:39:00 debian-8gb-sfo2-01 gdeliveryd: notice : formatlog:trade:roleidA=3328:roleidB=2161:moneyA=0:moneyB=0:objectsA=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;:objectsB=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;
    [1] => 2016-07-31 00:39:00 
    [2] => 3328
    [4] => 2161
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;
    [8] => 38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;
)
```

Comment: What about `\w+=(?:(?:(?:\d+(?:,\d+)*);)+|(?:\d+(?:,\d+)*)?)(?::|$)`? If you don't want the objects separate you can just wrap that regex in `(?:)+`

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: see [this](https://regex101.com/r/qVzs25/2)

Comment: @ctwheels I'm using PHP (the same code the other question). I'll update with the code .

Comment: @webmasterdro if you give us everything you need in one question we might be able to give you a more appropriate answer. It looks like you're trying to do many things using as few regex as possible. If that's the case you might want to look at the `(?(DEFINE))` construct. See it in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/3EmKCX/1)

Comment: @ctwheels I'll update the question

Comment: Add expected result.

Comment: Alright. I updated the question with the current code and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For are navigating through this question, sometimes: ***less*** is more. The pattern **(.*)** will do the trick.

```
([\d-: ]+)\s*.*\sformatlog:trade:roleidA=(\d+):roleidB=(\d+):moneyA=(\d+):moneyB=(\d+):objectsA=(.*):objectsB=(.*).*$
```

Answer (score 4):

**Regex**: [`^(?:\s?\d+(?:[-:]\d+){2}){2}|\w+=\K[^:]+`](https://regex101.com/r/iiWLRM/3)

Details:

- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `|` Or

**PHP code**:

```
$string = "2016-07-31 00:39:00 debian-8gb-sfo2-01 gdeliveryd: notice : formatlog:trade:roleidA=3328:roleidB=2161:moneyA=0:moneyB=0:objectsA=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;:objectsB=38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;";

preg_match_all('~^(?:\s?\d+(?:[-:]\d+){2}){2}|\w+=\K[^:]+~', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-07-31 00:39:00
    [1] => 3328
    [2] => 2161
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;
    [6] => 38155,54,1;38155,53,1;38155,45,1;38155,47,1;38155,46,1;2000,55,1;38155,50,1;38155,49,1;38155,48,1;38155,40,1;38155,41,1;38155,42,1;38155,43,1;38155,51,1;38155,52,1;38155,44,1;38155,35,1;38155,33,1;38155,32,1;38155,34,1;38155,36,1;38155,38,1;38155,39,1;
)
```

[Code demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10ef6dfaf4f6288587ddff9c2314d30cd37437c5)

Comment: @webmasterdro No problem. I updated my post and regex.

Comment: Hello, I tested your example reading the whole file (in while loop) and looks like your regex returns an multi-dimensional array: array ( [0] => array () ) but since is in the while loop, there's no need to be a multi - dimensional array. Using the following regex: `/([\d-: ]+)\s*.*\sformatlog:gshop_trade:userid=(\d+):(.*)item_id=(\d+):expire=(\d+):item_count=(\d+):cash_need=(\d+):cash_left=(\d+).*$` I get the desired output.

Comment: It's from another type of log (on the same file). Can you update your example to return like that? Screenshot from terminal: http://prntscr.com/ibt259